# create a folder/directory in matlab and write some fasta files inside of it in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to cerate a fold in my current working directory and then write a fasta file inside of it. This is what I did for a toy example.

```
>> mkdir('t1');
>> fastawrite('\t1\fasta.txt', 'wsx', 'rfv')
```

And I got the following error:

```
Error using fastawrite (line 62)
Could not open file fasta.txt for writing.
Check write permissions in the directory \t1.
```

Then, I right clicked the folder with name t1, added it to the matlab path and tried it again. But still, it does not quite work here. Could anyone tell me the reasons? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A leading backslash indicates a absolute path, looks like you want a relative path. Remove the first backslash.